# Reordering numbers

Tags: math, permutation, shuffle, random

I have numbers in range 1-62
I want to be able to "crypt" them, so that it's hard to guess they are generated in some order.

So, it should be some mapping, for example

1->35
2->19
3->61
...

so that I have 1 to 1 mapping, 100% reversible.

---

I can hardcode mapping, but I would prefer math solution to that, some kind of formula which takes number as argument, and produces number in range 1-62, and does NOT generate duplicates. Is there any chance this formula exists?

---

Just for history, validation script:

```
<?
  $test = array();

  $val = 37;
  for($i=0;$i<62;$i++)
  {
    if($test[($i*$val)%62])
    {
      print("Collision: $i ".$test[($i*$val)%62]."<br/>");
    }
    $test[($i*$val)%62] = $i;
    print("$i => ".(($i*$val)%62)."<br/>");
  }

?>
```

**Update:**

Here are IDs generated thanks to these answers:

```
qpOLHk
NMb84H
aI740D
x5urn0
UsROKn
hPeb7K
EcByu7
1zYVRu
oWlieR
LjIFBe
8G52YB
v3splY
SqPMIl
fNc95I
Cazws5
ZxWTPs
mUjgcP
JhGDzc
6E30Wz
```

Sweeeeeet :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the numbers 1 to 62 in an array and shuffle the array (for example using the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)). The index of the array is then mapped to the content of that cell (but be careful of the off-by-one error if you use 0-indexed arrays).

To make it deterministic use a particular seed for the random number generator.

Edit: A less computationally expensive (and also easier to guess) mapping is to multiply by some constant and then calculate the result modulo 62:

```
result = (input * 37) % 62
```

The number 37 is just an example. You can use any number that is [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime) to 62 - that is any odd number apart from 31.

Comment: This goes for hardcoding I was considering. static seed would do, but I afraid it's too much processing, I need something simple...

Comment: @BarsMonster: How much processing is allowed? And what part of this algorithm do you see as too expensive?

Comment: This would be performed 10'000 times per second in interpreted language. While I see that your solution probably fits in terms of performance, I really like to have something like output = (input+35)%62, but a little bit more random.

Comment: @BarsMonster: How about `(input*37) % 62` ? Or `pow(input, 37) % 62`. The latter can be computed quickly using repeated squaring and taking the modulus at each step. And of course add 1 to make the range 1-62 instead of 0-61.

Comment: It gives duplicates, for multiple input values same output.

Comment: @BarsMonster: Are you sure? Can you give an example of two inputs that give the same output?

Comment: @Mark Byers: You are genious, everything except even numbers works as valid multiplicator. Not sure why I was sure there will be duplicates... Thanks alot, that solves my problem perfectly :-D

Comment: @BarsMonster: Even numbers won't work, and also 31 also won't work. If the number is coprime with 62 it will work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime I'll update my answer to include the multiplication suggestion since it seems to be that which you have accepted.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Thanks. That's a rare case when I see that math really works :-D

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of Mark Byers's comment. Find the inverse of `x` mod n (e.g., n=62).

Let `x` be your input integer in the interval `[1, n]`. Use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find `y` and `t` such that `xy + nt = 1 mod n`. Then `y = x^{-1} mod n`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look at this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php#93759) on the [`str_rot13()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA). It's quite easy to implement (well, depends on the language) and here's a [worked example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#A_worked_example).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's output is numbers modulo some big number => I do not see how does it maps each value to some other value without duplicates in specified range.

Comment: @BarsMonster: You're right. I didn't see that you needed outputs from 1-62 as well.